# Why does javascript have different performance in script tags vs. js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with a jquery function that animates the title of my homepage. When I had the javascript execute in my html, everything worked great (text animates immediately). When I moved the function into a separate .js file, the text flashes first and then it animates.

html that javascript is being run on:

```
<h1><a href="#home">This i</a></h1>
```

javascript in html:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".letter-container h1 a").lettering();
    });
</script>
```

javascript when moved to .js file:

```
$(function() {
        $(".letter-container h1 a").lettering();
});
```

My questions are:

1. Why does the javascript perform differently when placed in script tags in the html file vs. when placed in a separate .js file
2. Is there any way I can keep the function in the .js file and fix the delay?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the <script> section in the HTML?
And where are you then including the file in the HTMl when you move it to a separate .js?

Comment: You may be interested in [developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rules_intro](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rules_intro). Here is a list of articles from the Google Developer Network that explains the order in which browsers load, parse and render JavaScript that may help answer your first question.

Comment: What else do you execute onReady?

Comment: The script section was at the bottom of the HTML file and when I move it to a .js file the file is included in the head of the HTML file.

I have a few other functions that execute onReady but this is the first one.

Comment: If you change the location of the script, then that is another variable that can affect it's execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When put in a separate `.js` file, it requires the browser to make a separate HTTP request (if the resource isn't already cached). That means that networking becomes the enemy. If you set up caching properly with your server, this shouldn't be too much of a problem.

Other than that, the Javascript is interpreted/compiled the same.

Comment: How would `defer` or `async` shorten the delay?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah I wish I knew what I meant by that. I'll delete it. Can you think of anything else to add to the explanation? I'm not sure I can think of anything else that could make a "delay"

Answer (score 0):

It's not only network traffic (downloading additional js) but also the point **when** the javascript is executed.

If you have the code

```
<div id="div1">
......
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
myfunction();
</script>
<div id="div2">
....
</diV>
```

`myfunction` will be run after the div1 is created, but before div2.

However, if you run some function from .js included in header it will run after the whole page is loaded (I assume you're using `$.ready()` or something similar). Because browsers are showing elements during the page load (except you place everything in `table`) the effect is you'll see the text flashing.

Comment: In both cases, he uses `$(function() { ... })`, which is short for `$.ready()`.

Comment: hmmm so probably he adds something more to $.ready queue, and therefore the code delayed direct in HTML is queued first, and so executes first anyway. I have no idea what else it could be.

Comment: You could be right. One way to check is to move loading the `.js` file to the end of the HTML file, and run the code directly (that is, without `$(function() { ... })` around it).

Comment: generally if you want to modify an element immediately so that the user would not notice it, you should place script tag directly after. But in OP's case both invokes are deferred. I'm wondering if it's not a kind of puzzle, and downvotes are the punishment for not guessing...